# position:absolute element not positioned correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating my first jQuery plugin and have a somewhat working example (see http://tapmeister.com/test/selector.html) and script below. I have been struggling with positioning an element for days.

The desired look and functionality starts with showing some text and an optional down arrow to the right of the text. Upon clicking, the text/arrow is replaced with a list of options with the currently selected option highlighted and at the same location of the original text. Clicking an option makes it the currently selected option, and initiates a user defined callback, and clicking any other space closes the dialog.

The plugin replaces the original select element, and I wish to preserve whether it is inline or block.  When making them inline, however, the position:absolute `<ul class="selectIt-list">` popup does not appear above it's associated text `<span class="selectIt-text">`.  Since both the span text and ul popup are both in position:relative `<div class="selectIt">`, why is it located to the far left?

As a side note, a major reason why I am doing this is to learn a consistent pattern on how plugins should be built. I am strongly basing my approach on http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring (any reason I shouldn't?). I am hoping someone can review it, confirm whether I am correctly interpreting how to build a plugin, and provide any suggestions. I am also not sure whether I really get the whole namespace thing.  Maybe I should post this as a separate question?, but I don't know whether asking for code critique is appropriate.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
        <style type="text/css">

            /* CSS associated with plugin */

            div.selectIt {
                position:relative;
            }

            span.selectIt-text {
                color: #2C46B7;
                cursor: pointer;
                font-family: Verdana;
                font-size: 10px;
                display:inline;
            }

            span.selectIt-text,
            ul.selectIt-list {
                padding: 7px 3px 5px;
            }

            ul.selectIt-list {
                display:none;
                margin:0px;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                border: 1px solid #B3B4A7;
                z-index: 50;
                box-shadow: 3px 1px 6px #505050;
            }

            ul.selectIt-list li {
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                color: #393926;
                list-style-type: none;
                font-family: Verdana;
                font-size: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 2px;
                padding-left: 2px;
                padding-right: 2px;
            }
            ul.selectIt-list li.selectIt-hover {
                background-color: #DFDED8;
                color: #393926;
            }
            ul.selectIt-list li.selectIt-selected {
                background-color: #737060;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                cursor: default;
            }

            /* CSS Not associated with plugin */

            ul.myList > li {
                list-style-type: none;
                display:inline;
            }
            #horizontalList select.mySelect {
                display:inline;
            }
            #verticalList select.mySelect {
                display:block;
            }
            span.label {
                color: rgb(57, 57, 38);
                font-family: Verdana;
                font-size: 10px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            span.selectIt-text {
                background-image: url("dropdown_arrow_blue.gif");
                background-position:right center; 
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                padding-right: 10px; /*Override padding-right to allow for image*/
            }

        </style> 

        <script> 
            /*
            * jQuery SelectIT
            * Copyright 2012 Michael Reed
            * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
            * 
            */
            (function( $ ){

                var methods = {
                    init : function( options ) {
                        //console.log('init');

                        // Create some defaults, extending them with any options that were provided
                        var settings = $.extend({
                            'class' : null, //Applies custom class so user may override
                            'extraWidth' : 0,  //Extra space to add to width to allow for user image css
                            'click' : function(){}   //Some user defined code.
                            }, options  || {}); //Just in case user doesn't provide options

                        //Apply events that should only happen once (unlike what is done by http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Events. Why did they do it that way?)
                        $(document).on('click.selectIt',methods.close);

                        return this.each(function(){

                            var $t = $(this),
                            data = $t.data('selectIt');

                            //Replace element
                            var list = $('<ul/>', {'class': "selectIt-list" }),
                            length,
                            max=0;
                            $t.find('option').each(function(i){
                                var $this=$(this),
                                text=$this.text(),
                                length = parseInt($this.css('width'));
                                max = length > max ? length : max;
                                list.append( $('<li/>', {text: text}))
                            });
                            max=max+settings.extraWidth;
                            list.css('width',max+'px');

                            var selectIt = $('<div/>', {class:"selectIt"+((settings.class)?' '+settings.class:'')}) //Didn't work to display same as original element: display:$t.css('display')
                            .append($('<span/>', {class:'selectIt-text',text:$t.find(":selected").text()}))
                            .append(list)
                            .css({display:$t.css('display')});  //Set to same as original element

                            //Apply events
                            selectIt.on('click.selectIt','span.selectIt-text',methods.open);
                            selectIt.on('mouseenter.selectIt','ul.selectIt-list li',methods.mouseenter);
                            selectIt.on('mouseleave.selectIt','ul.selectIt-list li',methods.mouseleave);
                            selectIt.on('click.selectIt','ul.selectIt-list li',methods.click);

                            // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet.  Why?
                            if ( ! data ) {
                                // Do more setup stuff here
                                $t.data('selectIt', {
                                    target : $t,     //Not really sure where this will be used
                                    selectIt : selectIt,  //Will be used when removing in destroy method
                                    settings: settings  //Save here so other methods have access
                                });

                            }
                            $t.hide().after(selectIt);
                        });
                    },

                    destroy : function(e) {
                        //console.log('destroy');
                        return this.each(function(){
                            var $t = $(this);
                            $t.off('.selectIt'); //Removes any events in selectIt namespace
                            $t.data('selectIt').selectIt.remove();   //Removes element from page
                            $t.removeData('selectIt');   //Removes data in selectIt namespace
                            //Should the original element be made visible?
                        })
                    },

                    open : function(e) {
                        //console.log('open');
                        methods.close();
                        var $t=$(this),
                        $p=$t.parent(),
                        index=$p.prev().prop("selectedIndex"),
                        list=$p.find('ul.selectIt-list').show();
                        list.find('li.selectIt-selected').removeClass('selectIt-selected');
                        list.find('li').eq(index).addClass('selectIt-selected');
                        var top = 0 - list.find('li').eq(index).position().top;
                        list.css({top: top});
                        e.stopPropagation();    //Don't trigger documents click
                    },

                    //If this is all I am doing, can change to just using CSS psudo class.
                    mouseenter : function(e) {
                        $(this).addClass('selectIt-hover');
                    },
                    mouseleave : function(e) {
                        $(this).removeClass('selectIt-hover');
                    },

                    click : function(e) {
                        //console.log('click');
                        var $t=$(this);
                        if(!$t.hasClass('selectIt-selected'))
                        {
                            var $p=$t.parent(),
                            $pp=$p.parent(),
                            select=$pp.prev(),
                            index=$t.index(),
                            option=select.find('option').eq(index),
                            value=(value=option.val())?value:option.text();
                            select.val(value).prop('selectedIndex',index);
                            $pp.find('span.selectIt-text').text($t.text());
                            select.data('selectIt').settings.click.call(this,value);
                        }
                    },

                    close : function(e) {
                        //console.log('close');
                        $('div.selectIt').find('ul.selectIt-list').hide().parent();//.find('span.selectIt-text').show();
                    },

                    update : function(content) {alert('When will this type of method be used?');}
                };

                $.fn.selectIt = function(method) {
                    if ( methods[method] ) {
                        return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
                    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
                        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
                    } else {
                        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.selectIt' );
                    }    
                };

            })( jQuery );

            $(function(){
                $('select.mySelect').selectIt({
                    //'class' : 'whatever',
                    'extraWidth' : 0,
                    'click':function(value){
                        switch(value)
                        {
                            case 'first':console.log('Do something first');break;
                            case 'second':console.log('Do something second');break;
                            case 'third':console.log('Do something third');break;
                            default: console.log('Do something default');
                        }
                    }
                });

                $('#horizontalList button.destroy').click(function(){
                    $('#horizontalList select.mySelect').selectIt('destroy');
                });

               $('#verticalList button.destroy').click(function(){
                    $('#verticalList select.mySelect').selectIt('destroy');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="horizontalList">
            <h1>Horizontal List</h1>

            <ul class="myList">
                <li>
                    <span class="label">Label</span>
                    <select class="mySelect">
                        <option value="first">First</option>
                        <option value="second" selected="selected">Second</option>
                        <option>Third</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="label">Some Label</span>
                    <select class="mySelect">
                        <option value="first">First</option>
                        <option value="second" selected="selected">Second</option>
                        <option value="third">Third</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="label">Some Label</span>
                    <select class="mySelect">
                        <option value="">First</option>
                        <option value="second">Second</option>
                        <option value="third">Third</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="destroy">Destroy</button>
        </div>
        <div id="verticalList">
            <h1>Vertical List</h1>

            <ul class="myList">
                <li>
                    <span class="label">Label</span>
                    <select class="mySelect">
                        <option value="first">First</option>
                        <option value="second" selected="selected">Second</option>
                        <option>Third</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="label">Some Label</span>
                    <select class="mySelect">
                        <option value="first">First</option>
                        <option value="second" selected="selected">Second</option>
                        <option value="third">Third</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="label">Some Label</span>
                    <select class="mySelect">
                        <option value="">First</option>
                        <option value="second">Second</option>
                        <option value="third">Third</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="destroy">Destroy</button>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a line in your JQuery [line 173]:

```
list.css({top: top});
```

Insert this line below it:

```
list.css({left: $(this).position().left});
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan,  Just figured out the same thing.  Still, why is it needed? Absolute positioning is relative to it's parent, no?  The parent is in the correct left/right position.

Comment: Not really. Absolute means the element's positioning is independent of any other element and strictly as dictated by the stylesheet, relative to the browser's zero point (top, left corner). In this case you do want to use Absolute, you just forgot to set the left position. Now don't hold me to this. This will differ with browser implementations. Just remember to always dictate your coordinates whenever you use absolute. :-)

Comment: Thanks Bryan.  Evidently you are right about always dictating coordinates, but not about always relative to the browser.  Per http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp, "An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is <html>".  I had a parent relative positioned element, so why was it not horizontally positioned to the left edge of the parent?

Comment: Yes. Correct. I forgot that little piece. I've always found browser behaviors inconsistent so I just assume I have to compensate for that by default. As for your relative position element, it could be a number of things, but I'm guessing the parent had no explicit coordinates?? OR your element had a z-index other than the parent and was throwing it off?? I'm not sure. I'd have to look at the code. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

For positioning what you described I would highly recommend using **jQuery's "my at of"** positioning. It's a huge headache saver!

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Position

Applying to your example, it would look something like:

```
//PLACE INSIDE YOUR EVENT HANDLER
$(".selectIt-list").position({
    my: "bottom center",
    at: "top center",
    of: ".selectIt-text",
  });
```

Comment: Thanks adanmb, I will check it out.  Also found that I can position left it to the correct location.  Still don't understand why it was positioned to the left of it's parent div.